# Как запустить демо-версию сервиса на tomcat?

Tags: java, сервер, веб-сервер, instagram, сервлеты

https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram-examples - использовал эти наработки

Note : Create a new client with the following redirect uri -
localhost:8080/BasicWebDemo/handleInstagramToken - **как я понял, нужно было просто зарегистрировать приложение, где указываем эту URL для ответа.**

Import the maven project in your favourite IDE. -**библиотеки импортировал.**

Open the config.properties in src/main/webapp/resources folder. 
Replace the clientId, clientSecret and callbackUrl with the values used during Client registration on Instagram Developer website. - **вставил свои данные, выданные при регистрации приложения**

Build the project and deploy the war file in your web server. - **собрал и упаковал в war, затем закинул по пути \apache-tomcat-8.0.26\webapps, перезапустил, в менеджере висит, но выдает 404**

Open the following URL : localhost:8080/BasicWebDemo - **ошибка 404**

*Прошу помочь, т.к. впервые с веб-сервером работаю и впервые за API, с использованием сторонних библиотек.*

[image][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы всё правильно делаете, за исключением интерпретации сообщений `/manager`. Нужно начать с логов. Что у Вас пишется в `catalina.out` по поводу этого `war`?

Вообще лучше `deploy` сделать через `/manager`, там и url можно определить и статус получить.

После выкладки логов, я обновлю ответ с более четкой причиной такого поведения.

---

> *Прошу помочь, т.к. впервые с веб-сервером работаю*

Tomcat это не совсем WEB-сервер. Это application server. Или как говорит [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) — конейнер сервлетов.

Я бы рекомендовал прочитать документация про это. Например, раздел [Деплоя приложения](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html).

Comment: Можно как-то добавить файл этих логов? Вообще вроде все нормально пишется про сам файл.

Comment: я прикрепил изображения логов. Про `deploy` есть в той документации? И еще такой вопрос, я случайно раздеплоил `/docs, теперь у меня этого нет, но как мне восстановить?

Comment: Снова поместить исходный каталог в /webapp

Comment: Я думаю, приложение, которое задеплоилось, будет доступно по ссылке http://[SERVER_IP]:8080/BasicWebDemo

Comment: Я ввел свой IP (ведь его же надо было?) и так же 404 

Разве мой IP не == localhost?